# Connect to internet, while wired to local network through ethernet

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, home-networking, network-adapter

I have my desktop computer connected to a few devices on a local network via ethernet and network switch. I changed my Internet Protocol Version 4 Properties to "Use the following IP address" and am able to successfully talk to the devices on my local network.

How can I connect this desktop computer to the internet while still remaining tied in to my local network via ethernet? Do I need to purchase another network card?

I have read the following posts and a few others, but do not think that they answer my question entirely as I do not have a WiFi card in my desktop machine:

[Connect to internet with wifi, while wired to a different LAN through ethernet](https://superuser.com/questions/740261/connect-to-internet-with-wifi-while-wired-to-a-different-lan-through-ethernet?newreg=3b31719b89de4fe79c0efd80b79468ab) 
[Connect to Internet through Ethernet, then use wifi for local network [Closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1321551/connect-to-internet-through-ethernet-then-use-wifi-for-local-network)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: More information is needed to properly answered this question.   Is there currently an Internet connection available to you, and if so how (ie is it on the same or a different LAN, what is its IP address and subnet and what is the IP and subnet of your PC).   Also, what kind (make and model ideally) of switch do you use and are you authorized to make network changes.  You most likely don't need another network card - but this depends a bit on how your network is laid out.

Comment: @davidgo I do have an Internet connection available on a different LAN. I am not authorized to make network changes on the Internet connection side, but can on the local LAN. The subnet of my PC and other local devices is 255.255.255.0. I "obtain an IP address automatically" in my Internet Protocol Version 4 Properties. I'd have to check on the switch make and model, but I believe its functionality is nearly identical to the one in my soon-following comment. Does this help? I can check other info in the morning.

Comment: @davidgo [Similar Network Switch](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122005&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Network+-+Switches-_-N82E16833122005&gclid=Cj0KCQiAxZPgBRCmARIsAOrTHSYf5NZdG65i2hslX7pKuWIDLcw8FUxoFS423I0QOPVjIjoZ1Mme6FkaAlAEEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). Thanks!

Comment: *Do I need to purchase another network card?* 2 separate (physically) networks needs 2 separate NICs. Yes, you do. And remember - you must have only one default gateway, for NIC connected to internet (obtained by DHCP as you tell above). Local network NIC settings must NOT have any default gateway (but a lot of routes to some subnets may exist). Of course, the subnets of NICs must NOT overlap. *The subnet of my PC and other local devices is 255.255.255.0.* It is the mask only.

Comment: We really need to know more about your LANs.  The "correct" way to do this would be to merge your networks together.  Alternatively, because you have a dumb switch, you most likely should get a second network card.  (It may still be possible to connect your LAN to the Internet LAN and run a second virtual interface on your computer - but without VLANs you risk unintended consequences).  Ideally you should provide a flowchart showing how the devices connect together, including IP addresses, subnet masks, switches and routers, and any constraints like devlces not allowed to talk to each other).