# Connect notebook PC to internet using Wi-Fi via Mobile Hotspot, while wired to a local LAN (through a router) using ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

I found '[Connect to internet with Wi-Fi, while wired to a different LAN through Ethernet](https://superuser.com/questions/740261/connect-to-internet-with-wifi-while-wired-to-a-different-lan-through-ethernet?newreg=c0d1fbf4bc47412b8ca6844152b7800a)' here and tried many of the config changes mentioned in the 6 Answers ... I did not think I should start a new Q., however, I am unable to Comment on that topic due less than 50 reputation here.
I met with some success changing the Automatic metric settings ... however ... I still find I cannot enjoy simultaneous connectivity ... before the metric changes, if I unplugged the notebook's Ethernet cable, I had Wi-Fi connectivity to the internet via my Mobile Hotspot ... as soon as I reconnected the notebook's Ethernet cable (to my router & LAN), I was able to browse my two LAN network drives but lost connectivity to the internet ... now, with the metric changes, the situation is exactly reversed, so, I think I'm close(r) to a solution, I just have to identify the conflicting IP config setting(s).
I'll paste in two TXT file captures of `ipconfig /all` (obtained in a CMD window) to illustrate where I'm currently at with all this.

NIC LAN (static IPs & metric of 2) & Wi-Fi Hotspot (DHCP IP & metric of 1), 1238PDT 08OCT20.txt

```
    Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\T40 User>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : IBM_T40_XP
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter TELUS Wi-Fi Modem - T3200M NetBEUI LAN, TCP IP LAN WAN:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connecti
on
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-09-6B-53-E6-66
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.200
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter FFF-2.4G:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Linksys Wireless-G Notebook Adapter
WPC54G Ver.3
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-18-F8-E2-23-7C
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.194
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, October 08, 2020 12:18:58
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, October 08, 2020 13:18:58

C:\Documents and Settings\T40 User>
```

NIC LAN (static IPs, Preferred DNS server & metric of 2) & Wi-Fi Hotspot (DHCP IP & metric of 1), 1243PDT 08OCT20.txt

```
    Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\T40 User>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : IBM_T40_XP
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter TELUS Wi-Fi Modem - T3200M NetBEUI LAN, TCP IP LAN WAN:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connecti
on
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-09-6B-53-E6-66
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.200
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1

Ethernet adapter FFF-2.4G:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Linksys Wireless-G Notebook Adapter
WPC54G Ver.3
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-18-F8-E2-23-7C
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.194
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, October 08, 2020 12:18:58
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, October 08, 2020 13:18:58

C:\Documents and Settings\T40 User>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "simultaneous connectivity"? Do you want to bond both connections to get more speed?

Comment: Hey Albin ... thanks for weighing in ... not looking to bond both connections to get more speed (also, please note: the router that forms the backbone of my LAN is not connected to the internet itself ... it's just present to act as a dependable hub) ... I just want internet connectivity on the notebook PC via Wi-Fi and the Mobile Hotspot (my Android 8.0.0 smartphone, a Samsung Galaxy S7 edge on the TELUS Mobility LTE network) in, say, the Firefox browser, while still being able to access a given device or devices on my LAN via (a) Firefox tab(s) using device's web page-style GUI(s) ... K_Mc

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what the problem is and what you are trying to achieve, or what kind of solution you are trying to get to work.

Comment: Albin ... I cannot access my hard-wired network drives (LAN NIC) while connected to my Hotspot (Wi-Fi NIC)... the objective is to be able to do both within the same Firefox browser.  I have figured out how to have one or the other but not both at the same time.

Comment: What's the make/model of your backbone router? If I understand the question, you want the main network to also be able to use the hotspot? I.e everything has access to the hotspot and local resources simultaneously?

Comment: Hey Tim ... don't really need or want the router (a Siemens Gigaset SE567) or network drives (WD My Book Lives) to have internet access ... only the notebook PC ... which is direct Wi-Fi connected to the Hotspot (S7 edge) ... I tried making the router's subnet the same as the DHCP subnet arbitrarily assigned by the S7 edge ... however, there is some IP config setting ... i.e. the Default Gateway assignment, Primary DNS Server assignment or TCP/IP metric on the notebook PC that causes the two interfaces to conflict and render one or the other unreachable in one browser session, multiple tabs.

Comment: ... so ... we're stumped on this?

Comment: ... bump ... there's gotta' be a way ... something simplistic too I bet ... but I still can't rationalize it out ...

Comment: ... bump ... I thought I'd bump this one more time to see if anyone else has any thoughts about this ... thanks, K Mc